# Функция определения высоты блока

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток всем. Помогите, пожалуйста, написать функцию для определения высоты блока.
У меня есть блок, высоту которого нужно определить. В нем будет какое-то текстовое содержание произвольного размера. По умолчанию указывается какая-то высота и если содержание в блоке больше нее, появляется кнопка "показать полностью блок" (показать, скрыть). Функция должна как-то получать id элемента. У меня есть вариант, но это не функция, а не совсем удобный скриптик.

```
$('#full').click(function(){
    $('#news1').stop().animate({height:'240px'}, 300, 'easeInCubic');
    $('#full').hide("slow");
    $('#smol').show("slow");
}); 
$('#smol').click(function(){
    $('#news1').stop().animate({height:'100px'}, 300, 'easeInCubic');
    $('#smol').hide("slow");
    $('#full').show("slow");
});
```

В JS не силен. Кто чем может, подскажите, пожалуйста или мб где подобные функции видели. Почитаю, разберусь. За любую помощь, буду благодарен. Самое главное чтобы высота блока определялась автоматически и разворачивалась на весь блок в зависимости от любого кол-ва содержимого. А начальный размер задавался в начала какому то определенному значению или передавался параметром в саму функцию (не особо важно).

Comment: Дляначалаоформитеправильновопрос,явотничегодажечитатьнехочу,даимногиетоже.

Так понятнее почему на вопрос никто не отвечает?

Comment: сейчас вопрос оформлен. изначально у меня всегда отображается без переводов строк.

Comment: Может додумаетесь наконец-то нажать кнопочку с циферками в редакторе вопроса? =)

Comment: ну сейчас же вроде все нормально отображается. все на своих строчках и код подсвечивается. я просто тут редко бываю, потому и так написано было каряво :)

Comment: Нормально отображается потому-что я нажал эту кнопочку за вас =)

Comment: огромное вам спасибо. я вижу кнопочку править, в ней цифры 101 оформить текст. я так понял ее надо было нажать

Comment: >У меня есть вариант, но это не функция, а не совсем удобный >скриптик.

Ну тогда как Вам помочь я не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите сделать кнопку "Показать полностью"?

Я делал по-простому)

```js
function toVisible(name1, name2) {
  $(function() {
    $("#" + name1).slideToggle("slow");
    $("#" + name2).slideToggle("slow");
  });
}
```

```css
div.article {
  display: none;
}

div.preview {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zaglav">Article</div>
<div class="article" id="article1"><br> Текст статьи
  <br><br>
  <a class="btnAr" id="butAr1" onClick="toVisible('preview1','article1')">Скрыть</a>
</div>
<div class="preview" id="preview1">
  <br>Предпросмотр статьи
  <br><br>
  <a class="btnAr" id="butAr1" onClick="toVisible('preview1','article1')">Подробнее...</a>
  <div>
```

Если интересно конечно же)

Comment: спс, работает :) самый простой способ что я нашел

Answer (score 0):

[$('selector').height();](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Comment: А как тогда правильно использовать getElementById()? я думал через него получить id блока. а функцию привязать к кнопочке показать полную новость. height() я так понимаю, определяет высоту элемента?

Comment: Ну вы дословно переведите getElementById - это же "получить элемент по id". Т. е. id нужно знать заранее, а это уже совсем другой вопрос. Скорее всего у вас спроектировано что-то не так, если вы не можете определиться с id.
На всякий случай -  без jq будет так:
height = document.getElementById('id').offsetHeight

Comment: Если ты используешь Jquery так и используй его, зачем тогда писать все на JS голом?

Comment: Я думал свою функцию написать) Вот и спрашиваю совета, как лучше поступить.

Comment: Потролю немного:

      var el = document.getElementById("id")
      // быстрее
      $("#id")

      // +
  
      function omg(elId) {var el = $("#"+elId) /имхо - выглядит ужасно/}

      function omg(elId) {var el = document.getElementById(elId)}
      // а тут многа букафф =)

     // единственное что лезет в голову и не нарушает
     // мое естетическое воприятие это что-то типа

     getElById = document.getElementById; // that's suucks, but...
     function omg(elId){var el=getElById(id)} // зато тут красиво =\


Спасибо за внимание :DDD